# Error : Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens

Tags: python, sdk, openstack, openstack-api

I'm trying to use the Openstack API for the first time with the Python SDK.
But I am getting below error:

```
Unable to establish connection to https://172.23.13.30/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.23.13.30', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff031441040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network unreachable'))
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't think this URL is correct. It should either include a port number, typically 5000: `https://172.23.13.30:5000/v3/auth/tokens` or something in the URL that identifies Keystone, such as `https://172.23.13.30/identity/v3/auth/tokens`. Therefore, find out where this URL comes from and correct it.